# How do I reference a folder that I copied with Automator action in a subsequent AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have close to zero AppleScript experience and very little Automator experience too, so please bear this in mind. What I'm asking might be REALLY obvious to you, but I'm somewhat stuck.

I want to create a workflow (saved as an App) where I can drag a folder and it does a few things:

- Copies the source folder
- Sets some background colors on the copied folders
- Deletes any folders that are empty

I found a script that does the deletion, but it was set to reference a specific folder. I want it to reference the folder that I have just copied:

tell application "Finder"

```
set the_items to every folder of entire contents of folder "$CopiedFolderHere"
```

...

[Image of the Workflow is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErNwX.png)

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me what I need to tweak in the script to allow it to make the deletions on the newly-copied folder.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you look at the default **Run AppleScript** action, a `run` handler should be used that declares an `input` parameter - this variable will contain a list of items passed from the previous action.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't embed the image of the workflow, but I have added a link to it. Could you take a look at the image and provide me any more pointers as to what I would need to change, please? I would really appreciate it :)